# Javascript - Every function an object?

Tags: javascript, function, object

In Javascript every function is an object.

```
function a() {
    this.x = function() { console.log("x"); }
}
```

Here "a" is a function, which is an object. right?

```
var b = Object.create(a);
b.x(); //does not work!!
```

The above code would work if we wrote -

```
var b = Object.create(new a())
```

So does that mean only the instance of a function is an object? not the function?

Comment: A function is an object, but inside the function `this` is not that object. It is the context set by the caller.

Comment: if you check - `a` variable does not have `x` property :-) so and inherited `b` also does not have it

Comment: Further to  Frédéric's comment, not only is `this` not a reference to `a`, in the code that didn't work you never actually call the function so the code inside it hasn't been run.

Comment: seems you a bit confused what do [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) function. this not call passed function as constructor, for new object, but just create new object and set prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not instance of functions you are messing with the new keyword the new keywords does many things:

- A brand new object is created
- The new object is [[prototype]]-linked
- The new object is set as the 'this' binding for the function call
- Unless the function returns its own object the newly invoked call
  function will return the new object

In your first example you are creating an object from function a which does not have any x property.

In the last you are creating and object of the object returned by the new a() invocation which has a x property because it is asigned in the execution of the a function

Comment: this is a pretty accurate explaination.

Answer (score 1):

What `this` is depends on how you use your `a` function. If you **don't run it as a constructor** function (you don't use a `new` keyword), `this` points to the outer scope. Try this:

```
function a() {
   this.x = function() { console.log("x"); }
}
a();
console.log(window.x());
```

On the other hand, when you write `new a()`, you **are running it as a constructor function**, in which case `this` points to the instance of newly created object. Try now this example:

```
function a() {
   this.x = function() { console.log("x"); }
}
var b = new a(); // mind the "new" keyword here
console.log(b.x());
console.log(window.x);
```

And as a simplest proof that every function is an object:

```
function c() {};
c instanceof Object; // ;-)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function a() {
  this.x = function() { console.log("x"); }
}

var b = new a();

b.x();
```

A function is like a `class`. You can create instances or objects using the `new` keyword.

Comment: I think it's clear from the question that the OP already knows that `new` creates an instance.

Comment: just wanted to specify the function is more like a class than an object

Comment: A function isn't *like* an object, it *is* an object.

Comment: There is no *class* in ECMAScript 5 even it acts partially like.

Answer (score -1):

Every function is a class not an object, every function value is an object. 
A class is a set of objects and a function is a set of function values, therefore every function is a class and in the spirit of pure functional programming, every function value is an object.